# Ubuntu & XFCE - Guake transparency

Tags: xfce, gtk, guake

I have Guake installed on Ubuntu with XFCE, problem with transparency. Instead windows below I see desktop wallpaper, what I can do with this problem?

Comment: for me it just slightly adjusts the colour brightness. I don't see anything through the console!

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the amount of transparency in `Guake's` preferences.

Click on the `whisker menu` and search for `guake` and choose `Guake Preferences`.

In here click on --> *Appearance* and then at the bottom you can adjust the transparency.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I don't know about this settings :). But transparency means that I see what's below. If below window I anyway see desktop wallpaper.